# FSL Mobile Flow How to Get Content Document ID

Tags: salesforcedx, visual-workflow, visual-flows

Im trying to get Content Document ID in FSL Mobile flow. But there is limitation about this, like the documentation says below.

*When uploading images in flows, the content document IDs parameter isn’t supported. Admins must create a flow confirmation screen to show which images were uploaded. Videos and other file types aren’t supported.*

Is there a way to get content document ID from newly uploaded file in fsl mobile flow ?

Answer (score 0):

Create a text variable and check the Allow Multiple values (collection)
Use the variable in the content document IDs parameter
This variable is a collection that stores the files’ 18-digit Ids after the upload. If there is no file, it will return [ ] (empty collection); If it has more than one file, it will return [ (18-digit Id), (18-digit Id)].

You can use the LEN() formula to count how long the “Content Document IDs” collection is. 2 means it has no file, 20 means it has one file (18 + 2 brackets), 39 means it has 2 files (18 * 2 + 1 comma + 2 brackets).

Answer (score 0):

FSL mobile flow we can only get the uploaded file name.

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mfs_flow_considerations.htm&type=5

[image]